# Why standalone search (Sphinx, Solr) instead of built-in package?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pretty basic use case: we want to fuzzysearch a mysql table based on one column, lets say it's a `name` column. E.g. this is my `users` table and I want to be able to find a user named "John Doe" if I search "Jon" or "Doe Jo" or "John" etc.

Coming from javascript land, there are quite a few packages out there that are just plug and play; add the package to our project and voila, we have can fuzzy search javascript objects using a simple api. Of course this involves no datastore, all of the data we want to search is already in a javascript object.

Now I'm trying to wrap my head around search with php + mysql, and it seems standalone options like Solr and Sphinx are popular. My question is, why? Are there not any good packages I can find on Packagist that are just "plug and play", which will search a particular table/column (I've looked, haven't found any, and the top results for "search" include Elastisearch, Solr, Sphinx)? If not, why not?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Sphinx and Solr are better at what they do than userland PHP code, because in order to be good at what they do they need to do things that PHP is bad at. Eg: building and traversing large, in-memory datastructures.

Comment: @nerdlyist right, so why not 1.) put all the relevant data into a php object 2.) search that object. Speed is the main reason? Could even put this object into memcached or similar

Comment: I would not bring in a whole system for fuzzy searching a name. Accept a percent of hits and write the SQL yourself. You also bring in the most valid point in JS it involves no datastore. As @Sammitch states in-memory is a lot different then for PHP and SQL

Comment: If that is your play then go for it. A quick google turned up https://github.com/Loilo/Fuse never used it but I am sure searching will get you something.